# Запись и чтение QVector <object>

Tags: c++, qt, файлы

Имеется `QVector <data> obj`. Как лучше реализовать бинарный файловый ввод-вывод?

```
class data{ 
     int var1; 
     QString var2; 
     bool var3; 
     bool var4; 
     void someFunc(); 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Перегрузить операторы `<<` и `>>` для класса, и записывать/читать вектор в `QFile` через `QDataStream` стандартным образом с помощью тех же операторов.

[Вот](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150827/) статья на хабре о сериализации объектов в Qt.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, и тем не менее, совет-то правильный.